# How to redefine \\ command inside a tabular using expl3?

Tags: tables, macros, luatex, expl3, hooks

When i try to redefine `\\` inside a tabular,my redefining not works. I understood,what probably after hook `\AtBeginEnvironment` something redefine my `\\` command,but i dont know,how to fix it. Help me please,how to redefine `\\` inside a tabular. Thanks everybody for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{
\cs_set_eq:Nc \\ {orig_endofline}
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \\ {
\orig_endofline
\message{new_line}
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a&b\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard...

Well, redefining is actually the easy part:  your code didn't work because one of the first things the `tabular` environment does is `\let \\=\@tabularcr`, so your redefinition is gone.  You have to redefine `\@tabularcr` instead.  Also remember that `\\` has an optional argument, so you have to cope with that too.  And since `\@tabularcr` is the actual command you want, you can redefine it just once, rather than at every environment.

The hard part is that after `\@tabularcr`, TeX starts scanning for `\omit`, so if you do `\message` at this point you completely break `\multicolumn`.  You have to either issue the `\message` (or whatever you intend to do here) *before* the original `\@tabularcr`, or inside `\noalign`.

You probably want to also take into account the `array` package and `tabularx`.  `array` undefines `\@tabularcr` and uses only `\@arraycr`, so you have to check for that.  The redefinition will depend if it happens before or after the package loads, so I put it `\AtBeginDocument` to be sure.

---

The generic `\kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn` takes three arguments:

```
\kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn <cr command> <star arg> <opt arg>
```

then it does

```
\use:x { \exp_not:N #1 \IfValueT {#2} { * } \IfValueT {#3} { [{#3}] } }
```

That line will `x`-expand everything:

- `\exp_not:N` prevents the expansion of `<cr command>`
- `\IfValueT {#2} { * }` expands to `*` or nothing, depending if there was a `*` argument
- `\IfValueT {#3} { [{#3}] }` expands to `[#3]` or nothing, depending if there was an optional argument

and finally become:

```
<cr command> <star arg (if present)> <opt arg (if present)>
```

---

Also note that `tabularx` will execute the environment body multiple times, so you may want instead:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \use:x { \exp_not:N #1 \IfValueT {#2} { * } \IfValueT {#3} { [{#3}] } }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF \@footnotetext \TX@trial@ftn
      { \noalign { \message{<<<<new_line>>>>} } }
  }
```

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,colortbl}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    % \message{new_line} % before or
    \use:x { \exp_not:N #1 \IfValueT {#2} { * } \IfValueT {#3} { [{#3}] } }
    \noalign { \message{<<<<new_line>>>>} } % after in \noalign
    %
    % \message{new_line} % this breaks \multicolumn
  }
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded{array}{ }
      {
        \cs_new_eq:NN \LTX@tabularcr \@tabularcr
        \RenewDocumentCommand \@tabularcr { s o }
          { \kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn \LTX@tabularcr {#1} {#2} }
      }
    \cs_new_eq:NN \LTX@arraycr \@arraycr
    \RenewDocumentCommand \@arraycr { s o }
      { \kozlovskiy_tabular_cr:Nnn \LTX@arraycr {#1} {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a&b\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{c and d}\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabularx}{2cm}{Xc}
a&b\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{c and d}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Now i almost understood,how to use commands with optional arguments. I want to clarify two things: Why we should use use:x variant and how to solve the problem in future,if my control sequences will have: things like orig@##1. In this case use:x will not works? 2. Why we use exp_not function?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I used `\use:x` to make the correct call to `\LTX@tabularcr` depending on the optional arguments given. If the table uses `\\[2pt]` (for example) then the call to `\LTX@tabularcr` will be `\LTX@tabularcr[2pt]`, and so on.  If you didn't use `\use:x` there it would not detect the optional arguments (try using `\\[2pt]` in the table and comment `\use:x` to see).  If the command you are copying is `##1` and you want to copy it to `orig@##1` then use `\cs_new_eq:NN { orig@##1 } { ##1 }`, then `\cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 } { ... }` or `\exp_args:Nc \RenewDocumentCommand { ##1

Comment: this doesn't work if the array package is loaded and so also it doesn't work with e.g. tabularx or colortbl (with different behaviour, depending on if the loading is before or after the code).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `array` support added. Thanks!

Comment: @phelype-oleinik Thank you very very much. Now,i hope,i understood,how use command with optional arguments. Let God bless you forever.