# two questions about longtable package

Tags: errors, captions, longtable, compiling, expl3

1. Why in \longtable package for end of line used two commands - @tabularcr and \lt@tabularcr. Because for my package \ command should use once for one line. Yes, I cannot redefine \lt@tabularcr command, and left only @tabularcr command, but it is very interesting for me to understand why for new line two commands calls. 2. How can I redefine \caption command for longtable. When I try to do it, I get an error:

   ```
   ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
   ```

Why does this happen? Thanks everybody very much for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_new_eq:NN\LTX@LT@tabularcr \LT@tabularcr
\cs_new_eq:NN\original@caption \caption
\cs_new_eq:NN\LTX@tabularcr \@tabularcr
\RenewDocumentCommand \LT@tabularcr{s o}{
\use:x{
\exp_not:N\LTX@LT@tabularcr
\IfBooleanT {#1} { * } \IfValueT {#2} { [#2]}
}
\message{new~line}
}
\RenewDocumentCommand \@tabularcr{s o}{
\use:x{
\exp_not:N\LTX@tabularcr
\IfBooleanT {#1} { * } \IfValueT {#2} { [#2]}
}
\message{new~tabularcr~line}
}
\RenewDocumentCommand\caption{s o m}{
\message{new~caption}
\use:x{
\exp_not:N\orig@caption
\IfBooleanT {#1} { * } \IfValueT {#2} { [#2]}
}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{test of long tables}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@tabularcr` is defined in the latex format (or a modified version in the array package) not in the longtable package

Comment: `\caption` acts like `\multicolumn{..}{....}` so must _expand_ to the tex  primitive column span, you can not have `\message{` or even `\relax` or `{}` or anything non expandable at the start.

Comment: similarly you can not have `\message{new~tabularcr~line}` at that point in your `\\ ` redefinition as that will stop `\multicolumn`, or `\hline` working following `\\` as they must be teh first thing in the row.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ok,i deleted \message in all commands redefinition,but error stil saved for \caption. Also why in longtable \@tabularcr and \ltx@tabularcr calls for \\,instead of one command.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question about (lt)@tabularcr as I say one is the original version from tabular and isn't defined in the longtable package at all, the other is an extended version from longtable that allows page breaking but calls the original internally.

Comment: your caption command is looking for an optional argument, that is not expandable, so that breaks column spanning,

Comment: you should have known not to add \message and that \@tabularcr comes from tabular as you had a long answer about exactly those things here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570114/1090

Comment: @david-carlisle Thank you very much. Now i understood,what \ltx@tabularcr use \@tabularcr. How now i can output debug message inside commands and what arguments should have \caption command. How i can redefine \caption command,to it works for \longtable and for \table too?

Comment: @David-carlisle how i can surround my \caption command by unexpandable commands?

Comment: You can not surround `\caption` (or `\\ `) with non-expandable material  you should probably hook into `\LT@makecaption` if you want to customise caption (and `\@makecaption` in the non-longtable case)

Comment: @David-carlisle How can i separately redefine \caption and label,using unexpandable material?

Comment: as I said, you can not do that. hook into \LT@makecaption not \caption.

Comment: @David-carlisle Ok,but how i can redefine label commands and what arguments expected \@makecaption hook? In If it's not s o m,how for sections,can you please advice for me,how i can redefine it,without doubling of code,because ideas,which i use,the same,but probably number of args is differents,so the differents only in use:x{...}.

Comment: This site can't really support general questions asking how a package works. Just look at the code. `\LT@makecaption` is defined by `\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%`  so in expl3 terms  an argument spec of `mmm`  any redefinition needs to preserve the same argument structure.

Comment: @David-carlisle \@makecaption have three mandatory arguments too? But section have s o m. So should i double code,to redefine commands with differents arguments,even if i use the same idea for redefining of this commands?

Comment: surely it is easier just to look at the source than ask?  You will need to look at the source anyway to know how to redefine. no it has 2 arguments `\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%`  see `article.cls`

Comment: @David-carlisle So,i should repeat my code three times for different argument structure ()sections,\@makecaption and \LT@makecaption and may be for \@nakelabel. I am not sure,but i somewhere saw \makecaption command,i.e not only \@makecaption.